# Make RAID over NFS?

Tags: filesystems, nfs, raid

I have a cluster with 25 machines. Each machine has a small SSD disk.

Can I organize the SSD disks of multiple disks as RAID-0 over NFS?

(HDFS is not an option. The application requires a direct read from file system.)

Comment: Why would you do that?  The bottleneck in networked filesystem is typically the network.  Therefore combining them together would simply accentuate the current bottleneck.

Comment: The machines are connected with Infiniband network which is blazingly fast compared to the normal SSD

Comment: You could search for `cluster NFS` or `HA NFS` for hints on how to do that. It will be complicated, as there has to be a lot of communication and synchronisation. Maybe you could better manage exporting mounted NFS shares on one server.

Comment: 25 separate machines, each presenting a device to be used as part of a RAID-0 array?  Do you know that a problem with just *one* of the machines will make the entire file system unavailable, even if you could somehow have them presented to your cluster as a coherent NFS file system?  You probably should look at something like [Lustre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_%28file_system%29)

Comment: Why not try CephFS http://docs.ceph.com/docs/mimic/cephfs/?